# Using WMI and/or remote registry to find available memory slots

Tags: windows-server-2008, wmi

Certain monitoring programs such as Spiceworks list not only the memory sticks in use in a machine, but also somehow show which specific slots on the board are in use and which is using them. With WMI I can obtain a total number of slots and also I can get a list of all of the devices, but the "DeviceLocator" field in Win32_PhyiscalMemory seems cryptic and can be completely different from motherboard to motherboard.

My question is with WMI and/or remote registry, how can I find out which specific slots are in use like Spiceworks does? I'm developing a simple script to easily find all this information in a somewhat large network with many different hardware platforms, but all running Windows Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using `WMIC MEMORYCHIP`?  There are quite a few options available under the diffent sub-commands (and sub-sub-commands for that matter.)  Click [HERE](http://www.walkernews.net/2009/11/21/use-wmi-to-find-out-ram-slot-in-used-and-memory-size-of-each-slot/) for a bit more of a walkthrough.

Comment: That also returns essentially the same information, not making it clear which slots are vs aren't in use. I guess what I'm looking for in a sense is a way to list all of the slots and their contents if possible. It's possible because somehow Spiceworks does it, but I can't figure out how.

Comment: I've never used spiceworks but it's probably preconfigured with a model list that knows how many slots already.  Then it searches for what's in use and lines both up for you.  That's an educated guess... Belarc does the same thing.  It was clear on my workstations which were and werent in use.  If it listed a size, it was in use.  How many different models of server do you have?  It's readily available info as to the spec of any given server, so comparing what's in use vs. a baseline per model (csproduct command) should do it.

Comment: It doesn't appear to be possible to do what I want. Ben - SysAdminCircus's comment on using some sort of hardware profile and going against that seems to be the way Spiceworks does it, and I was never able find another way.